# How to play facebook embed video in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, html5-video, facebook-javascript-sdk, embedding

I embedded a facebook video in my phonegap app where I've got two different problems and I'm able to fix just one of them .

**1. first problem (fixed)** - the facebook video was not being displayed in my app. So I could fix it doing something like this

```
    .fb-video { width: 100% !important; height:100%!important;  } .fb-video span { width: 100% !important; height:4650px!important; } .fb-video iframe[style] { width: 100% !important; height:100%!important;  }
```

By the way I'm not sure if it's been doing the second problem, I think it not.

**2. second problem** - When I click over the video it is not being played. Here some snippet

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div data-height="250" class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"></div>
</body>
```

So how can I fix the second problem playing the video in phonegap app? Also I'm not sure if it's the right and easiest way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am having the same problem.
@fct did you find any solution?

Comment: @RishiVedpathak You can access directly the url hosted on cdn . It's been a long time actually I don't remember it exactly. Reaching the code out I can give you more details. You find any solution please post here.

Comment: @fct any luck? I am facing same problem

Comment: @alamnaryab it was long time ago. Try to get directly video url which facebook offers by api, also avoid cross domain problems.

Comment: I am also facing with same problem. Did any one find solution ??