# Facebook embed post on local html / cordova?

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I'm trying to embed a facebook post in a cordova app.
To do that I'm following the simple guide from FB:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

For example I created this page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <title>My Website</title>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <h1>My Embeded post</h1>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/netanya.muni/videos/1668384143481421/"  
  data-allowfullscreen="true" ></div>


  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.7'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This page render just find if I load it from a web server over http/https.
My problem is that once it is loaded over the file:// protocol/scheme it doesn't work. The FB sdk is loaded just fine, but it seems like the communication between the page and FB fails to provide the size of the window, which in turn causes the embeded post/video to get css size of 0px over 0px.

Maybe this should not be the way to embed posts in cordova apps?

My post is similar to:
[How to play facebook embed video in phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368658/how-to-play-facebook-embed-video-in-phonegap)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784845/locally-embed-facebook-posts

Comment: @sean-kinsey maybe u know?